# jquery slideshow, index not advancing

Tags: jquery, indexing, slideshow

hi people am having a problem that i cant work out, i am using [imageswitch](http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/imageswitch/) to create a slideshow.

i have the following jquery:

```
// set up slideshow
    var IdxTR = <?php echo($totalRows_rs_gallery); ?>;
    var Idx =0;

    var ChangeImage = function(){  
        console.log('Idx: '+Idx+' - IdxTR: '+IdxTR+' Img: '+$(".SlImage").eq(Idx).attr("rel"));
        //If the image still animating, stop it and start the new one  
        $("#mainImage").ImageStop(true,true);  
        $("#mainImage").ImageSwitch({NewImage: $(".SlImage").eq(Idx).attr("rel")});    
        //Set the next image will be display  
        Idx = Idx++; 
        console.log('AFTER --- Idx: '+Idx+' - IdxTR: '+IdxTR+' Img: '+$(".SlImage").eq(Idx).attr("rel"));
        if(Idx>IdxTR){  
            Idx = 0;  
        }  
        //Start preload the next image  
        $.ImagePreload($(".SlImage").eq(Idx).attr("rel"));  
     };  
     var StartSlideShow = function(){
        IntervalKey = setInterval(ChangeImage,1000);
    };
StartSlideShow();
```

and in my html i have:

```
<div id="topcontainer">
<img id="mainImage" src="images/gallery/<?php echo $row_rs_gallery['image_gly']; ?>" />
<?php do { ?>
  <div class="SlImage" rel="images/gallery/<?php echo $row_rs_gallery['image_gly']; ?>"/>
  <?php } while ($row_rs_gallery = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_gallery)); ?>
</div>
```

the first console.log outputs: Idx: 0 - IdxTR: 8 Img: images/gallery/alison.jpg

but the second consloe.log does not display and when the ChangeImage() function runs again the idx is not advanced and the first console.log outputs the same: 
Idx: 0 - IdxTR: 8 Img: images/gallery/alison.jpg

any ideas why the index is not advanced? or why the second console.log does not run?

[test page is here](http://new.camerich.co.uk/information3.php?id_sec=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably want to fix the errors your javascript makes first. It keeps on outputting this:

```
Idx: 0 - IdxTR: 8 Img: images/gallery/alison.jpg
jquery-1.4.3.min.js:55Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined
information3.php:20Idx: 0 - IdxTR: 8 Img: images/gallery/alison.jpg
jquery-1.4.3.min.js:55Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined
information3.php:20Idx: 0 - IdxTR: 8 Img: images/gallery/alison.jpg
```

and so on.
The error seems to be after your console.log, but if it before your Idx++, it will never be changed from the 0 , and that's what your are seeing

addition:
Now I'm getting confused (*starts coffee*), but check this.:
Try the simple `Idx+1` way, or `++Idx`.

From [this page](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript_increment_decrement_operators.php3) (quite random page, I admit)

```
var a = 5;
   b = a++;
    (b contains the initial value of a, which is 5.
    a, on the other hand is now equal to 6)

   var a = 5;
   c = ++a;
    (In this case, JavaScript first adds 1 to a, changing
    its value to 6. This value is returned to c.
    Thus, c = 6)
```

I don't know what's happening in your case, but try the simple `+1` method please?

Comment: hi thanks, i cant see the other error in firebug? i commented out everything between the console.log and Idx++, the second console.log runs now but the index still isnt advanced
http://new.camerich.co.uk/information4.php?id_sec=2

Comment: nice, you can put a hold on that coffee... changed Idx = Idx+1;
now index is advancing, time to look at trhe other bits, what did you use to get that oher error? i am on firebug 1.62 and it doesn't show up.

Comment: I'm using google chrome, and I did the rightmouse-inspect element to check some stuff, and it reported the bugs